# ImportError: No module named win32api while using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a new learner of Scrapy. I installed python 2.7 and all other engines needed.

Then I tried to build a Scrapy project following the tutorial http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html.

In the crawling step, after I typed `scrapy crawl dmoz`  it generated this error message

```
ImportError: No module named win32api.
[twisted] CRITICAL : Unhandled error in deferred
```

I am using Windows.

Stack trace:

[image]

I am using Windows.

Comment: the version of my Scrapy  1.0.3.  And aslo [twisted] CRITICAL : Unhandled error in defferred:

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Perhaps you could try installing win32api.

Comment: I run this on windows

Comment: As stated in the installation guide, you should install `pywin32`. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Comment: How to install win32api

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvotes...even in 2017 the scrapyd tutorial does not mention needing win32api or installing pywin32.  I hit the same issue as 李皓伟 ran into.  Thanks to this question my problem was solved.  I think the bigger issue is that I came into the installation from http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html instead of the other linked docs which have way more detail.  Also, the linked documents don't mention pywin32 in my quick page search.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, and google search led me here.

Comment: yeah, Im upvoting this question, as the oficcial installation guide doesnt mentions the pypiwin32 module. Tho it recommends installing scrapy with conga, so maybe that's why. Either way, this is a good question and it has helped a lot of people.

Answer (score 62):

Try this.

> `pip install pypiwin32`

Answer (score 3):

If you search a bit along the internet you will find the following documentation which describes what you have to do to install Py32Win: http://www.feedbackward.com/content/scrapy_install.pdf

Here are all the steps described you have to do. I did it with this document and now my Scrapy installation works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error

> An Error Occured while trying to start the kernel
>    in the Spyder IDE and my error said 'No module named win32api'

My console/kernel was fixed by installing `pypiwin32` by putting `pip install pypiwin32` into the Python Command Prompt