# Scrapy crawl not recognized -> ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'win32api'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

TL;DR it works now; posting for the benefit of others who may have this problem. Cheers!

working with python 3.6.5 64-bit using conda
have scrapy 1.6.0 installed and recognized by visual studio code
copy and paste documentation code

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

try to run from powershell

```
scrapy crawl quotes
```

which returns

```
Scrapy 1.6.0 - no active project

Unknown command: crawl
```

looked at:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3344

- and saw the probable issue is that I am not in the correct file
  level, however i am in the directory that contains my project and
  powershell in visual studio recognizes scrapy.
- Since I am in visual studio getting to scrapy.cfg is a bit convoluted
  & when I navigated there it gave me very weird errors and did not
  recognize scrapy.
- all relevant subdirectories in this directory recognize scrapy but
  not scrapy crawl.
- post also mentions I must be in the project dir- I'm not sure what
  that means since I'm relatively new to programming- I believe that
  refers to the dir of my spider.py file...
- Also scrapy.cfg contains nothing but default values

when copy pasting into the convoluted spiders dir under
..conda\pkgs\scrapy-1.6.0-py36_0\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders

- the same issue occurs, as does running the command from all higher
  level directories
- also copy pasting scrapy into spider file leads to real bad errors

**update:** running

```
scrapy startproject <folder containing spider>
```

lets me run scrapy crawl...
but leads to a whole new mess of errors for scrapy crawl quotes ->

```
scrapy list
```

returns null / no usable spiders

running

```
scrapy genspider <dummy> <new dir>
```

created the necessary files to start running spiders -> I copy & pasted my quotes spider into this folder and ran

```
scrapy list
```

(this recognized the print statement I had at the end of the quotes spider as a new spider and now I cant get rid of it...? ok ig)

running scrapy crawl quotes... aaaand
big long scary errors. Great.

searching the last line in this error brings me to
[ImportError: No module named win32api while using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586454/importerror-no-module-named-win32api-while-using-scrapy)
which recommends using

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

after this we run scrapy crawl quotes and voila, we get a long scary response in the terminal, but its a working script with a lot of outputs. the files the tutorial says should be there are there and produce the right output when ran. (missing some formatting but content is correct)

I believe my question is solved and I will post this for anyone who happens to have this issue in the future.

This is different from the question mentioned because this question includes their answer as well as how I reached that point from crawl not recognized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named win32api while using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586454/importerror-no-module-named-win32api-while-using-scrapy)