# The win32 library is not missing even though it has been installed

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pywin32

I tried to do a project with a Scrapy scraper, which worked well so far, from zero. To use Scrapy I need to have a 'win32api' library. I have installed it in my virtual environment, but it doesn't recognize it and keeps showing me the error.

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\bass2\scraper>python -m pip install win32api
Collecting win32api
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32api
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\bass2\scraper>scrapy crawl sephora -o perfumes.json
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7
:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.2.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-S
P0
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 16ea497e99400f83
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "http"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_handler
    dhcls = load_object(path)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11 import (
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "https"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_handler
    dhcls = load_object(path)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11 import (
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3DownloadHandler" for scheme "s3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_handler
    dhcls = load_object(path)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\s3.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http import HTTPDownloadHandler
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11 import (
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

2021-01-18 10:45:57 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

And I did installed pywin32:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\bass2\scraper>python -m pip install pypiwin32
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\tests\bass2\scraper\scr_env\lib\site-packages (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\tests\bass2\scraper\scr_env\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (300)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And got the same error.

I also tried the solution proposed by XXX

```
pip install -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple pypiwin32
```

It get installed but I still have the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I also tried what seemed to work in my previous Scrapy scraper:

```
python -m pip install pywin32-ctypes
```

Comment: Looks like common problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586454/importerror-no-module-named-win32api-while-using-scrapy . Have you tried to install `pypiwin32`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, unfortunately